# Confused about vector identity

Tags: vectors

So in certain papers I have seen people use the following vector identity:

$\hat{a} \times  (\hat{a} \times \hat{c} ) = - \hat{c}$

where $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{b}$ are unit vectors. Intuitively this makes sense. However I need to prove it to make sure I'm correct. I know the vector triple product is given as:

$\hat{a} \times  (\hat{b} \times \hat{c} ) = \hat{b} ( \hat{a} \bullet \hat{c} ) - \hat{c} ( \hat{a} \bullet \hat{b} ) $

now assuming $\hat{a} = \hat{b}$ we get something to the effect of

$\hat{a} \times  (\hat{a} \times \hat{c} ) = \hat{a} ( \hat{a} \bullet \hat{c} ) - \hat{c} ( \hat{a} \bullet \hat{a} ) $

Since $\hat{a} \bullet \hat{a} = 1$, I believe it would make the above:

$\hat{a} ( \hat{a} \bullet \hat{c} ) - \hat{c} ( \hat{a} \bullet \hat{a} ) = \hat{a} ( \hat{a} \bullet \hat{c} ) - \hat{c}$

I don't see how $\hat{a} ( \hat{a} \bullet \hat{c} )=0$ to make the identity work. I must be missing something super basic but for the life of me I can't figure out what it is. Please help.

Comment: By your working, this will hold if and only if $\hat{a} \cdot \hat{c}=0$. Do you know that they are perpendicular?

Comment: That can't quite be true -- for example, if $a=c$ then $a\times(a\times c)$ is zero but $-c$ isn't.

Comment: I think Chappers nailed it. In the equations I'm looking at, A and C are indeed perpendicular. Can't believe I didn't see it before. Thanks so much.